# How to insert a value in an adjacent cell range based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, insert

I want my code to insert "190" in cell `B1` `if A1 is equal to "1"` and right after make the cursor to blink so the `B1` value could be complemmented with additional digits.

I have done this procedure. However it does work only for a cell and not for the entire range ()

```
Sub BULK()
 If range("A1").Value = 1 Then range("B1").Value = C190
End Sub
```

I expect the output to be "`C190`" and the cursor blinking to type additional digits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if i understand correctly but i'll give it a try. Assuming you have a range that you want to loop through and insert `C190` in column `B`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillValues()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ExtraDigits as Long

Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With WS
          LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

          For i = 1 To LRow
              If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).value)) = 1 Then
                 ExtraDigits = Application.InputBox("Add value:", Type:=1) 'If needed to enter different values modify from 1 to 2
                   .Range("B" & i).value = "C190" & ExtraDigits
               End If
          Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine! however I would like that after "C190" is displayed on the cell, the cursor blinks so I can add more digits and avoid to double-click to type additional digits.

Comment: @user3689783 Where are this digits coming from? You can concatonate to it if you already have a list with other digits that need to go to the end of C190.

Comment: Sure!, however I am not allowed to add additional columns so I can concatenate them. I have to copy these additional digits from a paper record.

Comment: @user3689783 instead of using the cursor, why not just add the extra digits using an inputbox?

Comment: @user3689783 I have updated my answer based on BigBen's suggestion. Every time you loop will prompt you with an input box to enter only digits. If you need text the application.inputbox will need at the end the value for text which is 2. This should solve the problem you have.

Comment: @user3689783 Alternatevely you can use `Application.SendKeys("F2")` that will enter cell edit mode but never tested this if it pause the loop until you finish editing and continues after. Not tested recomment using the `Application.InputBox` this will stop exectution until a value is entered.

Comment: F2 works fine. However, each time I type the additional digits they are erased once I press the Enter key.

Comment: @user3689783 I'm testing your theory on my mac and the data is still there. It's not clearning it at all. Unless you put the code in the loop and is doing something funny there. I strongly advise to use the `Application.InputBox`. I think this is the way to go it will pause the macro until you enter a value and then it will ask again for the next one i think this is a better approch than going in the cell with `F2`.